# WebSockets using Fleck. WSS

Tags: javascript, websocket, wss

I try to create simple chat application using secure layer WSS. Without wss it works. Here is my code:

```
        FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Info;
        var allsockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
        var server = new WebSocketServer("wss://localhost:8181");
        server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\sharpchat-master\server\Sharpchat\Certificate.pfx", "123");

        server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {   //See socket.ConnectionInfo.* for additional informations
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
                    Console.WriteLine("[NEW CLIENT CONNECTION]======================");
                    Console.WriteLine("GUID: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("IP: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Port: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientPort);
                    Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
                    allsockets.Add(socket);

                };

            socket.OnClose = () =>
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
                    Console.WriteLine("[DISCONNECTED CLIENT]=======================");
                    Console.WriteLine("GUID: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("IP: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress);
                    Console.WriteLine("Port: " + socket.ConnectionInfo.ClientPort);
                    Console.WriteLine("=============================================");
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
                    allsockets.Remove(socket);
                };

            socket.OnMessage = (message) =>
            {
                //TODO: Json.Net Deserialize
                Console.WriteLine("[JSON MESSAGE] " + message);
                allsockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
            };
        });

        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (input != "exit")
        {
            foreach (var socket in allsockets.ToList())
            {
                socket.Send(input);
            }

            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

When client connects to server there is an exception:

```
    [Warn] Failed to Authenticate System.AggregateEx
ception: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake
failed due to an unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncRes
ult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncRe
sult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar,
Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchron
ization)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an
unexpected packet format.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncRes
ult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncRe
sult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar,
Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchron
ization)<---
```

Here is client code in JavaScript:

```
    // Websocket Endpoint url
var URL = 'wss://localhost:8181';

var chatClient = null;

function connect () {
    chatClient = new WebSocket(URL);
    chatClient.onmessage = function (event) {
        var messagesArea = document.getElementById("messages");
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var message = "<"+ jsonObj.user + "> " + jsonObj.message + "\r\n";
        messagesArea.value = messagesArea.value + message;
        messagesArea.scrollTop = messagesArea.scrollHeight;
    };
}

function disconnect () {
    chatClient.close();
    }

function sendMessage() {
    var user = document.getElementById("userName").value.trim();
    if (user === "")
        alert ("Please enter your name!");

    var inputElement = document.getElementById("messageInput");
    var message = inputElement.value.trim();
    if (message !== "") {
        var jsonObj = {"user" : user, "message" : message};
        chatClient.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
        inputElement.value = "";
    }
    inputElement.focus();
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use full domain name in URL i.e. var URL = 'wss://localhost.company.com:8181';

Answer (score 0):

- Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost @ [Enable](http://chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost).
- [More Details are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142899/common-name-invalid-for-a-self-signed-certificate-for-websocket-server)