# "common name invalid" for a self-signed certificate for websocket server

Tags: ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, webrtc, ws

I'm trying to run this [webrtc client/signaling server code](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/tree/master/s/webrtc-from-chat), but after running the server with a new self-signed certificate I created by following the instructions of [this tutorial](https://ksearch.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/generate-and-import-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-osx-sierra/), my `chatclient.js` couldn't connect to socket server:

```
connection = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:6503/', 'json');
```

this is the error displayed by chrome's console:

```
(chatclient.js:106) WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:6503/' failed: 
    Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

I then go to `https://0.0.0.0:6503/` from chrome (the server is listening on port 6503), and this is the security tab from chrome inspector:

[image]

I'm guessing I need to set the correct common name during the generation of ssl certificate, to which I current set as `0.0.0.0:6503`.

What should I set? Since this is a websocket's address and I have no idea which part to write?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set it to `localhost` which is the same host you're trying to connect to. You do not need to include the port. Note that you will need a certificate in production.

You might also want to check the highly useful Chrome flag which ignores certificate errors on localhost: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: I just disabled the flag through chrome and it worked, Thanks a ton for the shortcut!!

Comment: This works. while both server and client @ localhost.